# How does one unsub from this stack?

Tags: discussion

I have had responses and help in other forums, but not so much as a greeting on this one. I don't need to see this stack, so how do I unsub? Perhaps it happens simply by not coming in here?

Comment: Heya, what exactly is it that you're seeing as part of being "subscribed"?

Are you trying to stop notifications and reputations changes? Are you getting a newsletter that you don't want to see anymore?

Comment: There is an 'Edit' feature in the top-left drop down menu, where you can choose which stacks you want on your list of "quick access"-stacks.. Here you can remove the ones you don't visit or like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "unsubscribe" feature that I know of, but you can delete your account if you want.

- [Meta Stack Exchange: How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

Comment: thank you for the answer. I enjoy other forums, so I will just ignore this one.